# Xcode 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, constraints, uidatepicker

I'm getting this exception in my project and I do not have any idea to solve it.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1e583670 UIDatePicker:0x1f83c590.bottom == UIControl:0x1e582160.bottom> view:<UIControl: 0x1e582160; frame = (0 0; 320 504); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e5822a0>>'
```

Basically, I have 2 screens (view controllers) in my app. I used a navigation controller for this.

In my 1st screen, I have two `textfields` , one `UIDatePicker`, and a `UIButton` that will send the user to the next screen(view). When the textfield is tapped, it shows a UIDatePicker instead of the usual keyboard to let the user input a date

I did this by writing this code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
// Set the input way for the date textfields
[startDateTextField setInputView:datePicker];
[endDateTextField setInputView:datePicker];
```

The two textfields share the one `UIDatePicker` (not that it matters, it's a start/end date thing). Also, the UIDatePicker is also hidden when running the application. It only becomes visible when a textbox is currently the `firstResponder`

The exception occurs after when I tap on a textfield, enter a date via the UIDatePicker, tap the button to go to the next screen, then tap the Back button to go back to the main screen.

But when I tap the button to go the next screen without tapping on a textfield and activating the UIDatePicker, I don't get any exception messages. So it's definitely a problem with how I used the UIDatePicker perhaps?

I created the UIDatePicker via xib drag-drop. I did not create it programmatically.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have exact issue with DatePicer and TextField.

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing the date picker when tapping the next button.  With [self.view endEditing:YES];  Sounds like the date picker is not being cleaned up properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting the error. I also have that line in my viewWillDisappear method